# How to remove title and channel icon from YTPlayer view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ytplayerview

How can I remove the youtube logo and the video title from YTPlayer in iOS. The volume and full-screen button are inaccessible due to the overlapping of the channel icon and title.

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*showinfo* : This parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after September 25, 2018.

> This is a deprecation announcement for the showinfo parameter. In addition, the behavior for the rel parameter is changing. Titles, channel information, and related videos are an important part of YouTube’s core user experience, and these changes help to make the YouTube viewing experience consistent across different platforms.
>
> The showinfo parameter, which indicates whether the player should display information like the video title and uploader before the video starts playing, is also being deprecated. Following the change, the channel avatar and video title will always display before playback begins, when playback is paused, and when playback ends. The avatar being displayed is new behavior that will be consistent across all embedded players.
>
> These changes will become effective on or after September 25, 2018. After that time, the showinfo parameter will be ignored. The behavior following the changes is consistent with the current default behavior for embedded players with the exception of the channel avatar changes mentioned above.

for more detail you get the detail info from [youtube/player_parameters info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018)

Comment: I also faced the same issue , so I placed the one button for full screen and add get the videoplayer.currentTime passed to videoplayer clueID

Comment: There is an option for fullscreen in YTPlayer after removing the show info key. I have to change the width of the UIView to a little bit wider then I got a fullscreen option in the right bottom corner. Problem solved. @Anbu.karthik

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the **showinfo** key from parameters when we sent a request to get an embedded video

Comment: I’m seeing *currently* on iOS that if I pass in `showinfo=1` then the volume and fullscreen buttons appear in the bottom of the video and if I leave it out or set it to 0, then they show up at the top and get covered by the video title and uploader image.